# emacs: key binding for expand region

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

One of my favorite emacs plugins is expand-region.

It selects block code in a smart way. Their ready recommends binding
the key C-= to expand-region.  However, in the Mac OS terminal, C-= is not passed to the application by the OS.

So what two key combination can I use on OS X ? (It has to be quickly pressable , because I use expand region almost every minute)

Comment: I'd suggest a function key (e.g. F9): http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html.  You can figure out what a given key is bound to with `C-h k`, and decide if you want to override it.  A lot of keys that are distinct in a GUI are aliased to the same key in the terminal, there's fundamentally no way around that, and each user decides which defaults are unimportant enough to rebind.

Comment: In iTerm2, C-= is forwarded correctly to Emacs if "Report modifiers using CSI u" is enabled in the profile settings (Keys -> General).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are unable to use C-= is because you have an OS X shortcut which is using that key binding. You could either disable that shortcut or move it to another key binding, which would allow you to use C-= in emacs.

I'm running Emacs in a GUI window under OS X (El Capitan) and have C-= bound to expand-region.

If your running in a terminal, it is possible the terminal could also be stealing that key binding, so if you find nothing which matches in preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts, then look in your keyboard preferences.

In general, they way I find available keys to bind in emacs is to do the following

1. List current key bindings with C-h b and look to see what is already used and identify an available binding.
2. Use C-h k to verify the key is not bound and to verify the OS will pass it through. If nothing happens, they key is being stolen by the OS or terminal, in which case, either you choose another key or disable the binding at the OS/Terminal layer.
3. Once you have identified the key binding to use, use either global-set-key to define it globally, or a local key map and define-key to define it in a specific mode.

I tend to use emacs a lot under OSX and therefore, disable many of the OSX shortcuts so that I can use the keys inside emacs. As I work on both Linux and OS X, I like to try and keep my key bindings for emacs the same across both platforms.